# single-spa: importmap angular 14 library es module together with systemjs-importmap

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I am trying to get a running `single-spa` application with some angular micro frontends and a shared library `@myorg/mylib` for angular UI components.

`@myorg/mylib` is similar to https://github.com/angular-microfrontends/game-core, which is consumed in angular app https://github.com/angular-microfrontends/play and dependencies are resolved in browser at runtime with import maps defined in `index.html` by  `<script type="systemjs-importmap" src="/importmap.json"></script>`

you can see the sample importmap json for the github examplere at https://storage.googleapis.com/angular.microfrontends.app/importmap.json

[image]

`@myorg/mylib` generates build output in `es(.mjs)` format and if i import that with `systemjs-importmap` json directly as .mjs format, browser gives me runtime error `Cannot use import statement outside a module.` like so

[image].

I do not have a .umd format because angular does not create it any more [image]

If i import it with plain importmap, instead of systemjs-importmap, like below

```
   <script type="importmap" >
      {
        "imports": {     
          "@myorg/mylib": "http:someserver/myorg-mylib.mjs"
        }
      }
    </script>
```

i get runtime error

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to resolve bare specifier "@myorg/mylib" from http://localhost:4302/main.js
```

where `http://localhost:4302/main.js` is the angular micro app which is trying consume a component from `@myorg/mylib`

I already have a webpack config in the consumer app which tells webpack that not to worry about those dependencies at bundling time, as described in single-spa-angular docs

```
const singleSpaAngularWebpack = require('single-spa-angular/lib/webpack').default;

module.exports = (config, options) => {
  const singleSpaWebpackConfig = singleSpaAngularWebpack(config, options);

  // Feel free to modify this webpack config however you'd like to

  singleSpaWebpackConfig.externals.push(
    '@myorg/mylib'
  );
  return singleSpaWebpackConfig;
};
```

how to get this working so that i can share UI components from `@myorg/mylib` in other angular micro front ends.

Comment: I think the correct way to think is to include systemjs versions of external dependencies and for the @myorg/mylib, have a custom build config with  "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser" and customWebpackConfig

Comment: latest error: ERROR Error: The component 't' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available.

The component is part of a library that has been partially compiled.
However, the Angular Linker has not processed the library such that JIT compilation is used as fallback.
realted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74416857/how-to-include-babel-loader-linkerplugin-in-a-single-spa-webpack-config

Comment: continued here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74447634/single-spa-angular-sharing-angular-libaraywith-ui-with-another-angular-app-giv