# how to add webpack config to a single-spa generated webpack config file [single-spa+angular14]

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, single-spa, single-spa-angular

**how do i add the following configuration mentioned [here](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#consuming-partial-ivy-code-outside-the-angular-cli) to a single-spa generated webpack config file `extra-webpack.config.js` ?**

> ```
> import linkerPlugin from '@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel';
>
> export default {
>   // ...
>   module: {
>     rules: [
>       {
>         test: /\.m?js$/,
>         use: {
>           loader: 'babel-loader',
>           options: {
>             plugins: [linkerPlugin],
>             compact: false,
>             cacheDirectory: true,
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     ]
>   }
>   // ...
> }
> ```

**//extra-webpack.config.js** (note the difernce in format)

> ```
> const singleSpaAngularWebpack = require('single-spa-angular/lib/webpack').default;
>
> module.exports = (config, options) => {
>   const singleSpaWebpackConfig = singleSpaAngularWebpack(config, options);
>
>   // Feel free to modify this webpack config however you'd like to~
>   singleSpaWebpackConfig.externals.push(  
>   
>   );
>   return singleSpaWebpackConfig;
> };
> ```

---

*Why am i trying this: to share an `angular library` with UI components in a `single-spa` framework with other angular micro apps. The library will be loaded once via `systemjs-importmap` like documented in single-spa. this is the snippet from anuglar.json file for the library if useful*

```
 "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "projects/my-lib/src/index.html",
        "main": "projects/my-lib/src/main.single-spa.ts",
        "customWebpackConfig": {
          "path": "projects/my-lib/extra-webpack.config.js",
          "libraryName": "@myOrg/my-lib",
          "libraryTarget": "system",
          "excludeAngularDependencies": true
        },
        "deployUrl": "http://localhost:4304/"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "tsConfig": "projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
        },
        "development": {
          "tsConfig": "projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.json"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the way. althought it does not solve the original intent of my issue, the question here is answered.

```
import pckg from 'single-spa-angular/lib/webpack';
import pckg1 from 'webpack-merge';
import linkerPlugin from '@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel';
 

export default function (config, options) {
  const singleSpaWebpackConfig = pckg.default(config, options); 

  return pckg1.default(singleSpaWebpackConfig, {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: [linkerPlugin],
              compact: false,
              cacheDirectory: true,
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  });
};
```