# single-spa-angular sharing angular libaray(with UI) with another angular app gives error

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I get this error while trying to load a component from a shared angular library in single-spa. (the app and library are in angular 14)
[image]

```
**core.mjs:4082 JIT compilation failed for component class t{constructor(){console.log("I am inside my-lib-component")}ngOnInit(){}}
zone.js:192 Uncaught Error: The component 't' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available.

The component is part of a library that has been partially compiled.
However, the Angular Linker has not processed the library such that JIT compilation is used as fallback.

Ideally, the library is processed using the Angular Linker to become fully AOT compiled.
Alternatively, the JIT compiler should be loaded by bootstrapping using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server',
or manually provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.
    at getCompilerFacade (core.mjs:4101:15)
    at Object.ɵɵngDeclareFactory (core.mjs:29496:22)
    at main.js:1:1247
    at main.js:1:1593
    at main.js:1:2699
    at Object.execute (main.js:1:2705)
    at i (system.min.js:4:3448)
    at t (system.min.js:4:3417)
    at system.min.js:4:3280
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)**
```

I followed the documentation here to include babel link configuration like [here](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#consuming-partial-ivy-code-outside-the-angular-cli) in the angular library but still nothing happens and i get the same main.js as output as before and hence the same error

[image]

```
//extra-webpack.config.js
import pckg from 'single-spa-angular/lib/webpack';
import pckg1 from 'webpack-merge';
import linkerPlugin from '@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel';
 

export default function (config, options) {
  const singleSpaWebpackConfig = pckg.default(config, options); 

  return pckg1.default(singleSpaWebpackConfig, {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: [linkerPlugin],
              compact: false,
              cacheDirectory: true,
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  });
};
```

here is my angular.json build config for the lib

```
"build": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "projects/my-lib/src/index.html",
        "main": "projects/my-lib/src/main.single-spa.ts",
        "customWebpackConfig": {
          "path": "projects/my-lib/extra-webpack.config.js",
          "libraryName": "@my-org/my-lib",
          "libraryTarget": "system",
          "excludeAngularDependencies": true
        },
        "deployUrl": "http://localhost:4304/"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "tsConfig": "projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
        },
        "development": {
          "tsConfig": "projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.json"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
```

how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i got the angular shared lib to work, with the standard config in angular.json (no single-spa modifications)

here is what i needed to do.

1. standard angular library config and output (es6)
2. tsconfig

   "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "compilationMode": "full"
   }
3. 

> npm install @babel/plugin-transform-modules-systemjs --save-dev

4. run a command to transform es6 module to systemjs format

> $> babel --plugins @babel/plugin-transform-modules-systemjs
> dist/fesm2015/my-lib.mjs -d dist/fesm2015/main

5. system-js import this new dist/fesm2015/main/.js in the importmaps.

Comment: I tried as mentioned above I go the below error


 Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel. comment